# Helm iterate with range bad carriage return after the dash

Tags: loops, yaml, range, kubernetes-helm

sorry for my poor english.
I try to iterate with range but I have a bad carriage return after the dash.
I tested different writings but I did not find my happiness.

run command:
helm template phototest . -f ~/repoGit/clusters/prod/helm-values/app-public/phototest/values.yaml -n phototestyfs --debug

my values.yaml:

```
topologySpreadConstraints:
  enabled: true
  contraints:
    - maxSkew: 1
      topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/datacenter
      whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
    - maxSkew: 2
      topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
```

My template:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
[...]
spec:
  [...]
  template:
    [...]
    spec:
      {{- if .Values.topologySpreadConstraints.enabled  }}
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        {{- range .Values.topologySpreadConstraints.contraints }}
        - {{- toYaml . | nindent 10 -}}
        {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
```

the output:

```
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        -
          maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/datacenter
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
        -
          maxSkew: 2
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
```

and I wish:

```
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/datacenter
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
        - maxSkew: 2
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
```

I tried this but the same result:

```
        {{- range $idx, $contraint := .Values.topologySpreadConstraints.contraints}}
        - {{- $contraint | toYaml | trimSuffix "\n" | nindent 10 }}
        {{- end }
or
        {{- range .Values.topologySpreadConstraints.contraints }}
        - {{- toYaml . | nindent 10 }}
        {{- end }}
or
        {{- range .Values.topologySpreadConstraints.contraints }}
        - {{- . | toYaml  | nindent 10 -}}
        {{- end }}
or
        {{- range $idx, $contraint := .Values.topologySpreadConstraints.contraints}}
        - {{- $contraint | toYaml | nindent 10 -}}
        {{- end }}
```

I tried with option indent instead of nindent and I get this output:

```
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        -          maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/datacenter
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
        -          maxSkew: 2
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
Error: YAML parse error on ilius-java/templates/deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 103: did not find expected '-' indicator
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 103: did not find expected '-' indicator
YAML parse error on ilius-java/templates/deployment.yaml
```

I searched on the web any solutions but I don't find.

Output of `helm version`: v3.8.0", GitCommit:"d14138609b01886f544b2025f5000351c9eb092e", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.17.5"}

Output of `kubectl version`:
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:45:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.1", GitCommit:"5e58841cce77d4bc13713ad2b91fa0d961e69192", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T14:12:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem you have is that you use `nindent`. The `n` stands for a newline, which is prepended.

> `{{ nindent $count $str }}`
> indent $str with $count space chars on the left and prepend a new line to $str

So in a nutshell, you cannot use `nindent`. However, it is valid yaml with the newlines, so you don't have to bother trying to fix it. Its not broken.

Comment: yes apparently is valid yaml but is not pretty output

Comment: @ysyldur, helm templating isnt a beauty contest. You should rarly see how it actually looks. Usually only if you use `helm template`, which I do for debugging at max. If you care about pretty output, you can always run it through a formatter.